# Sharepoint Library Search not including contents of custom content type

Tags: document-library, search

I'm having an odd problem with a document library where the "find file" searchbar is not including results from the contents of the files in the library, only the titles. The library contains a custom content type based on the Document Set that consists of a nested series of folders with recognized filetypes inside. (.docx, xlxs, etc.) If I search for a document content term from the main site seach, it returns the correct result, so it seems everything was indexed correctly. The issue appears to be with the library search only. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Trace the library search box query with your browsers dev tools (e.g. for chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). With the search query at hand, you'll be able to find the "faulty" difference between the library search and the search center.